# How to conditionally add RuntimeIdentifiers property to Directory.Build.props when using msbuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-8.0, avalonia, windows-application-packaging

I have a cross-platform solution with multiple projects targetting iOS, Android, Mac, Windows, and Linux using Avalonia. I am using [Windows Application Packaging Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) to package and deploy the Windows app. The main project has reference to various library projects, all of which target NET8.0.

When try to publish the Windows packaging project, unless I add `<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>` to every project (including the library projects), I will get an error like this

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Assets file 'C:\Projects\Samples\AvaloniaPackagingSample\AvaloniaPackagingSample.Desktop\obj\wappublish\win-x64\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.  AvaloniaPackagingSample.Desktop.Package C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    267
```

Instead of manually adding that build property to all projects, I have configured `Directory.Build.props` to apply that to all of the projects

```
<Project>

    <Target Name="ConfirmDirectoryBuildPropsImport" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild">
        <Message Text="Directory.Build.props has been imported successfully" Importance="high" />
    </Target>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Version>$(Version)</Version>
        <AssemblyVersion>$(Version)</AssemblyVersion>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The problem is that I have other targets besides the Windows and when I leave the runtime identifier Android/iOS build/publish would fail. So, I need a way to conditionally add `<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>`.

The idea is pretty simple - whenever I build the Windows app, indicate somehow that the runtime identifiers should be added, otherwise, skip them. I've tried adding a new variable called `IsDesktop` and add a conditional section to the `Directory.build.props`

```
<Project>

    <Target Name="ConfirmDirectoryBuildPropsImport" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild">
        <Message Text="Directory.Build.props has been imported successfully" Importance="high" />
    </Target>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Version>$(Version)</Version>
        <AssemblyVersion>$(Version)</AssemblyVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsDesktop)' == 'true'">
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MY_CUSTOM_DESKTOP_CONSTANT</DefineConstants>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64;osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

And then, I execute the msbuild command against the packaging project

```
msbuild $packagingProjectPath `
        /nologo /nr:false `
        /p:ProjectName="$PackagingProjectPath" `
        /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x64" `
        /p:Platform="x64" `
        /p:Configuration="Release" `
        /p:AppxPackageDir=$OutputPath `
        /p:AppxBundle=Always `
        /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint=$PackageCertificateThumbprint `
        /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile=$PackageCertificateKeyFile `
        /p:PackageCertificatePassword=$PackageCertificatePassword `
        /p:Version="$($EnvironmentSpecificVersion.VersionText)" `
        /p:IsDesktop=true `
        /v:detailed
```

However, the runtime identifiers are not getting added and the build fails.

2 observations

1. Notice how I've added this piece in `Directory.Build.props` `<Message Text="Directory.Build.props has been imported successfully" Importance="high" />` - when msbuild is executed this message does get printed, which means that `Directory.Build.props` is being picked up
2. I also see `MY_CUSTOM_DESKTOP_CONSTANT` printed out in the build log, which means that the conditional section does get activated

But anyhow, my build still fails due to the same error I was seeing before adding the runtime identifier: `...project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0/win-x64'`

What am I doing wrong? Perhaps, there's a different strategy for having conditional sections inside `Directory.Build.props`?

Comment: Going back to the error - are the `Restore` targets in the referenced projects being run before packaging? Are the projects run for `Restore` and `Build` prior to building the packaging project? Note there are differences between `msbuild /t:restore` and `dotnet restore` (which is unlike `msbuild /t:build` and `dotnet build`).

Comment: @JonathanDodds That was exactly my problem! I was using dotnet restore :( I switched to msbuild and it worked. I didn't have time to formulate the answer yet, but I will do it.